# How does an iOS app know the final user's language choice?

Tags: ios, iphone, localization

Let's suppose we've translated our application to a new language and we have the localization files in our project.
Now, how is the app going to know the language of the final user?

Is the app going to change the language depending on the settings of the iPhone/iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app determines which language to use based on the Region and Language set up by the user.

Comment: To be more specific to the original answer: this is in Settings, yes.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 13 and newer support language selection on a "per app" basis.

Apple Developer News: [How to support per-app language settings in your app](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=u2cfuj88)

Although, I have noticed the "per app" language selection capability may not itially be visible to the user ...

Starting with iOS 14, if a "per app language setting" via the Settings app is not accessible, *then some second language for the device in Setting > General > Language & Region needs to be added.* After any second language is added *at the device level*, then all language choices for the app are visible in the Settings > Some Example App > Preferred Language section.